# Can't forward a TCP socket in a bash script

Tags: bash, socket, binary

I have four TCP sockets connected to a device.

These are created with

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT
exec 4<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT
```

In a subshell I read from the file descriptors

```
cat <&4 | while read LINE; do
    echo -n "FD4 $LINE" | xxd -ps | sed 's/../&\ /g' > somefile.txt
done &
```

to forward it to a file for further usage.

But with some type of messages I have a problem.

With a simply

```
cat <&6 | xxd -ps
```

I see the following (some parameters).

```
006ec94430020000c090006800c903470000000000040000209f00000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

But I can not forward this to a file or variable to work with it.

I already tried it in different ways, but can't find a solution.

I hope someone know how to handle a message like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- at each line read, you recreate `somefile.txt` hence erasing what was put at the previous line. You should probably use `>> somefile.txt` instead, or move `> somefile.txt` after the `done` keyword.
- it seems you are receiving binary data (according to `xxd` dump) but your process it as if it was textual data separated by new lines. With binary data, `read` and `echo` won't work properly.

Why not simply pass the content of a file descriptor to `xxd` and save the result to a file? I.e. just this:

```
xxd -ps <&4 | sed 's/../&\ /g' > somefile.txt &
```